# C - Notify When A Background Process Is Finished

Tags: c, process, posix, wait

I am creating a small shell program, one functionality of my shell is to be able to run commands in the background.

If a job is run in the background, then a small message is shown notifying the user of the pid.

Furthermore, I want to also be able to notify the user of when the background job is done

This is my code so far:

```
int execArgs(char *argv[], int bg)
{
  int   pid ;
  int   child_info = -1;

  if(argv[1] == "exit"){
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);    
    }

  if ( argv[0] == NULL )        /* nothing succeeds */
    return 0;

  if ( (pid = fork())  == -1 )
    perror("fork");
  else if ( pid == 0 ){
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    perror("cannot execute command");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {

        if(bg == 0){
            if ( wait(&child_info) == -1 )
        perror("wait");
        }
        else
            printf("The Process PID:%d has started\n", pid);

  }
  return child_info;
}
```

I know the answer lies in something to do with the

```
pid_t return_pid = waitpid(process_id, &status, WNOHANG);
```

but I don't understand how to use it completely, what does 'status' mean?

I tried implementing it like this:

```
int execArgs(char *argv[], int bg)

{
  int   pid ;
  int   child_info = -1;

  if(argv[1] == "exit"){
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);    
    }

  if ( argv[0] == NULL )        /* nothing succeeds */
    return 0;

  if ( (pid = fork())  == -1 )
    perror("fork");
  else if ( pid == 0 ){
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    perror("cannot execute command");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {

        if(bg == 0){
            if ( wait(&child_info) == -1 )
        perror("wait");
        }
        else
            printf("The Process PID:%d has started\n", pid);
            int status;
            pid_t return_pid = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG); /* WNOHANG def'd in wait.h */
            if (return_pid == -1) {
                /* error */
            } else if (return_pid == 0) {
                /* child is still running */
            } else if (return_pid == pid) {
                printf("The process PID:%d has finished\n", pid);
            }

  }
  return child_info;
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have read the man pages but they are a bit cumbersome and I don't understand them.

Apologies if the answer is elsewhere on StackOverFlow, I tried searching as thoroughly as I could.

Comment: The parent process will receive a SIGCHLD when a child exits. Without reading all that code, I suspect that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: If you really **don't** do anything other than waiting for the child to finish, you don't need the signal, just remove the WNOHANG, so `waitpid()` blocks until a child exits.

Comment: `argv[1] == "exit"` is wrong. Use `strcmp`